# wget.download displays an output "-1 / unknown" in python

Tags: python, ftp, wget, urllib3

I was trying to get a file from FTP server using `wget`.

So I wrote a following code:

```
import wget
filename = wget.download('ftp://un:pass@server/dir/file') #this line throws output
#fileprocessing
```

If I run this, it works as intended but it also shows this output "-1 / unknown".

Is there any way to suppress it?

Console:

```
>>> import wget
>>> filename = wget.download('ftp://un:pass@server/dir/file')
-1 / unknown>>>
```

Found Line 526 in [wget.py](https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-wget/src/default/wget.py) is displaying the output.

Digged even further and found the output is from Line 272 in `requests.py` under `urllib` package.

And the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/_sources/library/urllib.rst.txt) says,

> The third argument may be `-1` on older FTP servers which do not
>   return a file size in response to a retrieval request.

Any way to stop displaying this output?

Versions:

[Python - 3.7.2](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-372/)

[wget - 3.2](https://pypi.org/project/wget/) - [homepage](https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-wget/src/default/)

`urllib` is one of the built-in module in `Python 3.7.2`.

Comment: Did you forget to put quotes around your string?

Comment: It is a string. I'll edit the description. @ThomasSchillaci

Comment: Can you copy paste the full output here that you are getting from running this?

Comment: Added console output in the description @ruohola

Comment: Added which line in wget is displaying the output in description @ruohola

Comment: Can you be more specific about the versions of the files to whose lines you refer to? I've checked both and none seem to be relevant to your problem. Can you post a link to the code repository?

Comment: Added version details of used modules along with python version @MartinPrikryl